# Does anybody know date of publishing of following spirit rover image in NASA apod?

Tags: nasa

[image]

I want to find this image in the following linked index.
https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/archivepix.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was posted on [November 26, 2002](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap021126.html), with the caption "Name This Martian Robot."
There was an [essay contest](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/newsroom/pressreleases/20021104.html) to name the two Mars Exploration Rovers to be launched in 2003.
The winner was [Sofi Collis](https://mars.nasa.gov/mer/newsroom/pressreleases/20030608a.html), a third grader in Arizona.